# Bash array to Python list format within bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to convert a bash array like `echo ${b[*]}` that outputs something like `1 10 100 1000` to a list format in Python: `[1, 10, 100, 1000]` that can be ready to use by a Python program. I need to do the conversion in a bash script.

I was doing it with for and if checking the positions, but wondering if there's something cleaner. Thx.

Comment: You can't create a python list in a bash script without using python, so I'm a little unclear as to what you are asking ... You could pass the string `1 10 100 1000` to a python script, parse it as a string, and `split()` it into a list, if that helps.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the array as a list of arguments to python? `./your-script.py "${b[@]}"` and then read `sys.argv` in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
my_list=(1 10 100 1000 "alpha" "beta")
s=''
printf '['
for e in "${my_list[@]}"; do
  if [[ "$e" = $((e)) ]]; then
    q=''
  else
    q='"'
  fi
  printf '%s%s%s%s' "$s" "$q" "$e" "$q"
  s=', '
 done
printf ']\n'
```

Turns Bash array:

```
(1 10 100 1000 "alpha" "beta")
```

Into Python array:

```
[1, 10, 100, 1000, "alpha", "beta"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
echo "[${b[*]}]" | sed "s/ /, /g"
```

Comment: This will not work if Bash array elements contains space or strings

Answer (score 1):

It would have too many ways too answer this question :

1. If you have a list of items :

   ```
   my_list=(1, 10, 100, 1000); for i in $my_list; do echo $i; done
   ```
2. If you would make loop in range numbers:

   ```
   for i in $(seq 1 20); do echo $i; done
   ```
3. If you would return exactly power of ten:

   ```
   for i in $(seq 0 3); do echo $((10**i)); done
   ```

At the end I think your script would be third one, I hope it would be good to you.